# How is the gradient of this function calculated?

Tags: proof-explanation, machine-learning

From understanding machine learning: from theory to algorithms:

How is the equation in the red box below derived?

Isn't the gradient of the objective function

$$J = \lambda w^T w  + \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{2}(w^Tx_i - y_i)^2$$
equal to

$$\nabla J =  2\lambda w  + \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (w^Tx_i - y_i)x_i$$

And $$\sum_{i=1}^m (w^Tx_i - y_i)x_i = \sum_{i=1}^mw^Tx_ix_i - \sum_{i=1}^my_ix_i$$

How does the author get $A$ out of this gradient?

---

[image]

Comment: Looks like $A$ is defined in Equation 9.6, which is repeated in 13.4. That looks right, pending transposes and such.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{i=1}^n(w^Tx_i)x_i = w\sum_{i=1}^n(x_ix_i^T)$?  I see that $(w^Tx_i)x_i$ is a vector, but $wx_ix_i^T$ shouldn't be defined as $w$ has shape $(n \times 1)$ and $x_ix_i^T$ has shape $(n \times n)$.

Comment: It's not. $w$ ends up on the RHS of the expressions with $A,$ not the LHS.

Comment: How is $x_i x_i^Tw = w^Tx_ix_i?$

Answer (score 1):

From your initial expression:

$$
J = \lambda w^T w  + \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{2}(w^Tx_i - y_i)^2
$$

Gradient respect to the vector $w$ yields

$$
\nabla J = \lambda \nabla (w^T w) + \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{2} \nabla \left(w^Tx_i-y_i \right)^2,
$$
Let's compute the gradient of the single bits.
First bit
$$
\nabla (w^T w) = 2w.
$$
Second bit
$$
\nabla(w^T x_i - y_i)^2 = \frac{d(w^T x_i - y_i)^2}{d(w^T x_i - y_i)} \nabla(w^T x_i) = 2(w^T x_i - y_i) x_i.
$$

Let's back substitute

$$
\nabla J = 2\lambda w + \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (w^T x_i - y_i) x_i = 2\lambda w + \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (w^T x_i) x_i - \sum_{i=1}^my_i x_i
$$

Now let's analyze the summation

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m (w^T x_i) x_i = \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i^T w) x_i = X X^T w = A w,
$$
Here $X$ is the matrix constructed as
$$
X = \left[x_1 , \ldots,x_d \right]
$$
Observe that
$$
X X^T = \sum_{i=1}^mx_i x_i^T.
$$
I suppose, apart from dimensions checking, the most rigorous way to prove the equality is to prove that the two matrices $A = XX^T$ and $B = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i x_i^T$ define the same bilinear form, which means you need to check

$$
e_i^T X X^T e_j = e_i^T \left( \sum_{i=1}^m x_i x_i^T \right) e_j
$$
are the same for all $i,j$ ($e_i$ is the $i$-th vector of the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^m$), if you don't get confused with the indices you should be able to prove the equality.